# c++ compress with libzpaq to char* buffer

Tags: c++, vector, compression, buffer

I have a `std::vector<short>` and would like to compress (and later decompress) with the libzpaq from https://github.com/zpaq/zpaq/ to something like `char* buffer`.

However I don't get the concept of this `Reader` and `Writer` class mentioned in the header file. How do I put my `std::vector` in to get a compressed `buffer` out?

Currently I have something like the following code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libzpaq.h"

struct writer: public libzpaq::Writer {

  void put(int c) {

  }
};


struct reader: public libzpaq::Reader {

  int get() {

  }  
};


void libzpaq::error(const char* msg) { 
    fprintf(stderr, "Oops: %s\n", msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main() {


  short a[] = {2,5,8,2,4,2,2,2,6,5,4,3,4,2,2};
  std::vector<short> v(a, a+15);

  char* buffer;


  reader in;
  writer out;

  libzpaq::compress(&in, &out, "5");  

}
```

And I wan't to compress the vector `v` into `buffer`. (And later decompress it again.)

But I don't understand the concept of the `Reader` and `Writer` struct/class.

The docu (http://mattmahoney.net/dc/libzpaq.3.html) also mentions the functions `virtual int read(char* buf, int n)` and `virtual void write(const char* buf, int n)` for the `Reader` and `Writer`. How can I cast a `std::vector<short>` to `char* buf` end get the length in `n` bytes of this `buf`?

**Edit 1**: I found a class `StringBuffer` in libzpaq.h line 1376. But something like

```
buffer = reinterpret_cast<char*> (&v[0]);
length = sizeof(short)*v.size();


libzpaq::StringBuffer inString, outString;

inString.read(buffer, length);

libzpaq::compress(&inString, &outString, "5");

std::cout << "size outstring: " << outString.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << "size instring: " << inString.size() << std::endl;
```

always gives me

```
size outstring: 0
size instring: 0
```

Even if I try it with a much larger vector `v` of some thousend random elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Reader` you provide byte by byte access to the data you want to compress. So with `std::vector<short>` it would look like this.

```
struct reader : public libzpaq::Reader {
    reader(const std::vector<short>& v) :
    m_v(v),
    m_offset(0) {

    }
    int get() {
        if (m_offset < m_v.size() * sizeof (short)) {
            return *((char*) m_v.data() + m_offset++);
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    int m_offset;
    std::vector<short> m_v;
};
```

`Writer` should collect output data of the `Reader`. If you want to collect it in `char` array I could recommend to do it like this.

```
struct writer : public libzpaq::Writer {
    void put(int c) {
        m_buffer.push_back(c);
    }
    int size() {
        m_buffer.size();
    }
    void copy_to(char* dst) {
        memcpy(dst, m_buffer.data(), m_buffer.size());
    }
    std::vector<char> m_buffer;
};
```

Then call it:

```
writer w;
reader r(v1);

libzpaq::compress(&r, &w, "5");

char* buffer = new char[w.size()];
w.copy_to(buffer);
```

If you want to use `StringBuffer` then you should write some data to buffer, before read, that why it returns 0. Look at example:

```
char* buffer = reinterpret_cast<char*> (&v[0]);
int length = sizeof (short)*v.size();

libzpaq::StringBuffer in, out1, out2;

// fill buffer with source data
in.write(buffer, length);

// compress to out1
libzpaq::compress(&in, &out1, "5");

// decompress out1 to out2
libzpaq::decompress(&out1, &out2);

// check result
short* b = (short*)out2.data();

for(int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
    std::cout << b[i] << std::endl;
}
```